# What was this DIG (or may be D G ) Interface on IDE (PATA) CD Writer?

Tags: pata, pin

I hope this question is in scope for this site.

While I was just about to throw away my very old internal CD Writer (PATA Interface) in E-Waste, I saw two pins on its extreme left  back panel interface mentioning DIG ( D G being Pinouts) on it.

See the snapshot, the next one right to it is a 4 Pin Audio interface and next to that is Master/Slave/Cable Select pins.

Does anyone know what was this DIG? There’s absolutely no reference of it on the internet.

[image]

Comment: pure guess... S/PDIF? 'dig'...ital? That would make D, G digital & ground.

Comment: @Tetsujin your guess is right. I searched with reference of SPDIF and finally found the relevant reference here http://www.co-bw.com/DIY_SPDIF_Connection.htm

Comment: Oh man I miss CD burning...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is digital out. The digital auto out has both channels encoded and passed along one wire pair.

Not sure why it is labeled D/G--perhaps so you don't think you can connect it to an analog receiver--but it is signal and ground. The analog audio connector requires a pair for each channel, and it is labeled Right, Ground, Ground, Left. In reality, most analog audio connectors I have seen use a shared wire for ground so the connectors usually only have 3 wires.

Comment: "D" for "data"?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: probably. And also "D" for "Don't connect directly to a powered speaker?

Comment: D for Dance and G for Groove since it is audio output :)

Comment: it's DIG for DIG(ital)

Comment: @user1306322: I am referring to the D/G in the pin-out diagram below "DIG"

Comment: Data and Ground. Because getting them backwards could do Bad Things.

Comment: "The digital *audio* out ..."

Answer (score 20):

Digital Out. This is how it's labeled on my CD writer:

[image: sticker]

Google "cd spdif 2-pin" and you'll find suitable cables.

Answer (score 2):

Digital audio output for connecting to a sound card.  Back in the day it (or the analogue equivalent) was required to play CD audio through computer speakers

Answer (score 0):

DIG = digital (audio output). 
D = data
G = ground. 
Protocol should be compatible with S/PDIF standard, however electrical interface cannot be directly connected to any standard equipment. 
Signal output from CD have TTL or TTL-3v3 standard. This signal can be attached directly to any standard TOSLINK emitter but You need to add 5V supply or amplifier. 
This signal can be also converted to coax S/PDIF connector (signal level +/- 0.7V). Minimal set of parts include only two resistors and capacitor. Recommended set includes buffer (any logic gate).